# python requests.get() doesn't work on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, python-requests

I made a telegram bot that downloads manga from http://mangareader.cc.
here is part of my code:

```
class URL:
    def __init__(self, url:str):
        self.url = url

    def get(self) -> bytes:
        """return url content in bytes"""
        return requests.get(self.url, stream=True, allow_redirects=True).content

def GetChapters(url: URL):
    chapters = {}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.get(), 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'cl'})
    for chapter in table.find('ul').findAll('li'):
        chapters[chapter.span.a.text] = URL(chapter.span.a['href'])

    return chapters
```

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['manga'])
def manga(message):
    url = URL(message.text.split(' ')[1])
    chapters = GetChapters(url)
```

It works fine in local server, but when i deploy it on heroku the `url.get()` part doesn't work. it doesn't show any errors in logs, either.
What should i do so i can send http requests from heroku server?
(sorry if my english is poor. i'm not native.)

Comment: Saying "it didn't work" does not help us fix the problem.  Tell us what **actually happened**, and tell us what you **expected** instead.

Comment: If it didn't generate an error you should have received _some_ response. What was that response?

Comment: There's a decent chance that site just rejects (or sends empty responses to, or something else) requests coming from AWS as a way of _avoiding_ being scraped. Have you looked at its terms of service? Do they permit what you're trying to do?

Comment: first you could display `content` form `requests` to see if you get warning or something different. But some servers may block access to external portals to stop spamers/hackers